# Only show the lines that are in all textfiles at least once

Tags: sed, awk, perl

a.txt

```
cat a.txt
a
b
x
c
```

b.txt

```
cat b.txt
d
e
a
f
```

the q:

```
SOMEMAGICK *.txt
a
```

**Q:** how can I show only the lines that are in all *.txt files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
cat *.txt | sort | uniq -c | egrep "^ +$(ls -1 *.txt | wc -l) "
```

And then to get the number of appearances stripped off, you could add ...

```
cat *.txt | sort | uniq -c | egrep "^ +$(ls -1 *.txt | wc -l) " | sed -re 's/^ +[0-9]+ //'
```

As per the comment by @Stephane the above won't work if a line appears multiple times within a single file.  Here I sort and uniq each file first to avoid that:

```
for f in *.txt; do sort -u $f > $f.uniqd; done
cat *.uniqd | sort | uniq -c | egrep "^ +$(ls -1 *.uniqd | wc -l) " | sed -re 's/^ +[0-9]+ //'
```

Although now it's not a one-liner anymore. :)

Comment: sort *.txt | uniq -c | egrep "^ +$(/bin/ls -1 *.txt | wc -l) "

Comment: That doesn't work for lines that appear more than once in a file.

Comment: `sort -u` is a shortcut for `sort | uniq`. Also, `cat * | sort` can be shortened to `sort *`.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'FNR == 1 { FILENUM++ }
     SEEN[$0] == FILENUM - 1 { SEEN[$0] = FILENUM }
     END { for (s in SEEN) if (FILENUM == SEEN[s]) print s }' *.txt
```

### Explanation

When reading the first line of each file, increment `FILENUM`, so that when reading the *n* th file, `FILENUM` is *n*.

When reading each line, count the number of files in which that line has been seen (but you only need to bother doing this if the line has been seen in every previous file).

When there is no more input to read, print all lines that have been seen in all files.

**Caution:** As with several of the solutions posted here, this one also has a weakness.  According to the question, if any of the input files is empty, there is supposed to be *no output at all*.  However, since awk is a line-oriented tool, it ignores empty files.  That is, the `FNR == 1 { FILENUM++ }` fails to increment `FILENUM` for empty files.

With GNU awk, it's possible to fix this bug using the [`ARGIND`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html) built-in variable.

```
gawk 'SEEN[$0] == ARGIND - 1 { SEEN[$0] = ARGIND }
      END { for (s in SEEN) if (ARGIND == SEEN[s]) print s }' *.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk

```
awk '{
      x[$0][FILENAME]
     }
     END{
      num_files=ARGC-1;
      for (b in x)
       if (length(x[b]) == num_files) 
        print b
     }' a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Comment: how to use this? :\ :D

Comment: @gaskopeter, assuming you have 3 files `abc.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`, invoke the command exactly as above

Comment: it gives syntax error at 'x[$0][FILENAME]' - using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @gaskopeter, it would appear you are running on older version of awk

Comment: @1_CR `Ubuntu/Debian` uses `mawk` by default. Perhaps you are using a `gawk` feature?

Comment: @jordanm, you are right. I am using GNU awk

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
export LC_ALL=C
sort -u a.txt |
  comm -12 - <(sort -u b.txt) |
  comm -12 - <(sort -u c.txt) |
  comm -12 - <(sort -u d.txt)
```

Which would be relatively efficient, but that's not easy to extend to an arbitrary number of files.

Answer (score 1):

### For 2 files

This is no more complicated than making use of `grep`'s ability to use a word list. For example:

```
$ grep -f b.txt a.txt
```

#### Example

```
# a.txt
$ cat a.txt 
a
abc defg
de
bcd
xyz bcd
c

# b.txt
$ cat b.txt 
d
e bcd
a
f
bcd

# common lines to a.txt & b.txt
$ grep -Fxf b.txt a.txt
a
bcd
```

**NOTE:** Depending on the data you may need to add a `| sort -u` after the `grep` if any lines are duplicated in the files!

#### Details

```
-F, --fixed-strings
     Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, 
     any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

-x, --line-regexp
     Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  
     (-x is specified by POSIX.)

-f FILE, --file=FILE
     Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains 
     zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by 
     POSIX.)
```

### For 3 or more

You can use the fact that if you compare any one file to the others that what ever is common across all of them as compared to this one file, then all files must share this common line. Again using `grep -f` as above but this time we'll have to loop through the files using a `for` loop.

```
$ mf=""; for i in *.txt; do [ -z "$mf" ] && mf=$i && continue; grep -Fxf $mf $i;done | sort -u
```

If we add some additional files into the mix:

```
# c.txt
$ cat c.txt 
a
z
d bcd
e
q
bcd

# d.txt
$ cat d.txt 
a
z
e
z bcd
bcd
```

Running our code produces this:

```
$ mf=""; for i in *.txt;do [ -z "$mf" ] && mf=$i && continue; grep -Fxf $mf $i;done | sort -u
a
bcd
```

Comment: To get this to work with more than 2 input files, you are going to have to resort to process substitution

Comment: @1_CR - sorry I'm not following you in terms of the process sub. comment. I understand what you're saying by >2 .txt files. This approach could be modified so that you run it against 2+ files though.

Comment: I meant `grep -f <(grep -f a.txt b.txt) c.txt`, but I see that you seem to have solved it in a different way

Comment: @1_CR - thanks, makes sense. I wanted something that was more dynamic if there were *.txt files.

Comment: @200_success - thanks for pointing that out. Should be fixed now.

Comment: `grep -f` (as opposed to `comm` for instance) is going to be terribly inefficient as it compares all lines one to one. Your logic for "3 and more" is flawed, it reports lines that are in the first file and _any_ of the other files as opposed to _all_ the other files.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - yeah this A has been dogging me. Always felt like it was forced for the 2 or more situation. I see what you mean in terms of the flaw now. Don't see a way to salvage the approach. Think I should delete it or just take out the 3 or more bit? I feel like the `grep -f` bit for 2 is of value still.

Answer (score 1):

I like an easier solution using `join`:

```
join <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
```

This does work on your two input files, but may not behave as you expect on lines containing spaces, it will also output duplicate lines multiple times.

To remedy the second issue, just

```
join <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt) | uniq
```

The first is a bit more complicated, but I cheated a bit with the `-t` flag, to use a non-occuring charachter as field separator:

```
$ cat a.txt 
This test
foo bar
does work
$ cat b.txt 
This is a test
foo does not work
does work
$ join <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt) | uniq
does work work
foo bar does not work
This test is a test
$ join -t : <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt) | uniq
does work
```

Comment: This won't work for three files or more, then you would have to reside to the a loop as described by @slm